# overwrite existing table rows using DOCX4j

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I am facing a problem in writing in MS Word file using Docx4j. The scenario is something like:

First user writes into  the word file and supposedly he takes about 10 rows of the table and saves the file.

Second user comes and writes about 5 rows and saves the file again. But after sometime he again opens the file and modify something through java application.

Modified text is being added into the file instead of replacing the old text.

Now I want to replace his old text and want to save new paragraphs in table.
In simple words I want to replace old table rows with new one in Docx4j.

How can I reach to my desired rows to replace them?
Can anybody help me in this? Thanks

Comment: So can we assume you have a reference to the tbl object, and know which row you want to replace?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace to what you try do is just replace the String
Check this

> https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/replace-text-into-docx-within-a-table-t6.html